# How to click dynamic button using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I don't know how to click this dynamic button, which has no HTML element I can use to click.

I tried to Click the button by using 'find_element_by_tag_name' but it doesn't work.
I post the Code of the button here:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/n/?confirmemail.php&amp" style="color:#3b5998;text-decoration: none" target="_blank" tabindex="-1"rel="external"></a>
```

Comment: The link in 'href' is not complete because the link dinamically changes.

Comment: Go to the website in a browser, then right click on the button, click on inspect, then on the element in the inspect right click on it and mouse over copy, click on copyXPath, then click on the element by xpath

Comment: If the `href` attribute dynamically changes you need to identify the element from it's parent elements and you need to update the question with a bit more of the _outerHTML_

Comment: Hi @GKM__ , have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the beginning of the `href` you can use in the XPath `starts-with`:

```
dynamic_button_xpath = "//a[starts-with(@href, 'https://www.facebook.com/n/?')]"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(dynamic_button_xpath).click()
```

Hope this helps you!